# Where in practice can we see following information propagation model

Tags: social-network-analysis

I am not certain, if this is the right place to ask the following question. I am looking for some practical scenarios in social networks where the following information propagation model can arise:

[image: A toy example of the desired information propagation model]

Basically, I have a source node and some information propagating radially from it and each recipient receives the information from a single sender.

Comment: This is a [spoke-hub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoke-hub_distribution_paradigm) or [star network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_network). Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: Yes but a multi-hop star network can have a single node sending info to multiple recipients. Also, in spoke-hub a single node can receive from multiple nodes. I am looking for a model where there are radial lines coming out from a single node. Each radial line comprises cascaded nodes. Also, I want to know if a social network can mimic such network in practice.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the central node is at level 0 (root), this graph becomes a tree. Now it is easy reason about the different types of trees that can be formed and different types of social networks that can be modelled.

In order for the graph to be a tree, communication between nodes has to be restricted, such that the tree structure is not violated (e.g. two nodes on the same level cannot communicate). I can't think of any social network where communication is naturally restricted in this way, but such a social network can be created artificially.

Examples of such artificial social networks would commonly follow a chain-of-command structure. For example in a military setting, the official information flows would have a tree structure.

Comment: I also thought about it in those terms. The problem is that even in chain-of-command structures, there is communication between people within the same rank and there is also communication from one-to-many between different levels of the tree.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think this kind of graph will occur naturally in a system. Though in a military, officers at the same level cannot issue orders to others on the same level. And officers can't issue orders to juniors that are under a different officer.

Comment: Sure, although in the restrictive case of communicating orders, one officer can issue orders to several juniors.

Comment: Sure, multiple reciever nodes are still allowed if I understood what you asked correctly - _Basically, I have a source node and some information propagating radially from it and each recipient receives the information from a single sender._

Comment: Well, I didn't ask it but I understood it differently. I thought that the picture in the question disallowed several recipients for a single sender.

Comment: As Mr. Smith pointed out, I am disallowing several recipients for single sender. Anyways I think I should still select this answer. I do not think this question is wellposed and it may not occur in practice. The motivation for asking this question was the following. For such topology, the observation at the bottommost or the leaf nodes are independent given the source symbol. Most of the social networks that I have seen have links going all over the place.